# Angular 7 ng-bootstrap do not show Modal PopUp

Tags: angular

I'm using angular 7 and bootstrap 4 but do not show modal popup
it display  modal as default view. [this is the content of my package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gg4rM.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, share us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hayam, are you using ngx-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap and bootstrap. Choose what do you want (e.g. if you're using ng-bootstrap, not use bootstrap -just the bootstrap.css-, if you're using ngx-bootstrap not use ng-bootstrap, etc)

Comment: i'm using  ng-bootstrap and bootstrap

Comment: Please refer link : https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(RequirementFormComponent);
    modalRef.componentInstance.moduleId = this.moduleId;
    modalRef.componentInstance.moduleName = this.moduleName;
    modalRef.componentInstance.projectId = this.projectId;
    modalRef.componentInstance.projectName = this.projectName;

    modalRef.result.then(() => {
      this.loading = true;
      this.loadRequirements(this.projectId, this.moduleId);
    });
  }